# Cannot Receive Incoming call on Twilio android Client

Tags: android, node.js, twilio

I am Developing an android application for making calls,using the Twilio API. I am able to make an outgoing call from the twilio android client,but I cannot receive any incoming calls. So what additional code needs to be written on the server side apart from assigning the incoming capability. I am using node js for the server.

//android code

```
    public void onInitialized() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        capabilityToken = HttpHelper
                                .httpGet("/my server url/token");   
                        device = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken,null);

                    /* Code to handle incoming connections */

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,HelloMonkeyActivity.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                device.setIncomingIntent(pendingIntent);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG,
                                "Failed to obtain capability token: "
                                        + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }

            }).start();

        }


//establish a connection
    public void handleIncomingConnections(Device inDevice,
            Connection inConnection) {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
        connection = inConnection;
        connection.accept();
    }
```

//server code

```
    var express=require('express');
     var app=express();
     var twilio=require('twilio');
     var acctId='my account id';
     var authToken='my token';
     var applicationId='my apps id';

    app.get('/token',function(req,res){
        var capability=new twilio.Capability(acctId,authToken);
        capability.allowClientIncoming('client');
        capability.allowClientOutgoing(applicationId);
        var token=capability.generate();
        console.log("token:"+token);
        res.send(token);
    });

    app.get('/call',function(req,res){
    var caller_id="//Twilio number";
    var twiml=new twilio.TwimlResponse();
    var dialTo=req.query.DialTo;
    twiml.dial(dialTo,{callerId:caller_id});
    res.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

Comment: U need to send client name in your API when you are collecting capability token from your server.One thing is very important  might be some issue due to network so please check on GPRS conenction.

Comment: I have implemented HelloMonkey Demo now its working fine.Once you register with the client name (such as "test" or "bob") then you can call from mobile origin client to mobile Receiver client by using that client name(such as "test" or "bob").

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

[`device = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken, this);`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client/incoming-connections)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

It looks like you are not wiring up the Device's Listener when you call [createDevice](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/android/Twilio#createDevice_String__DeviceListener_).

```
device = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken,null);
```

Should be:

```
device = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken,this);
```

Where `this` implements the [DeviceListener](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/android/DeviceListener) interface:

```
public class MonkeyPhone implements Twilio.InitListener, DeviceListener
```

Twilio uses the DeviceListner interface in order to launch the activity that notifies you that there is an incoming connection.

I would also suggest checking your Twilio Call logs to ensure that there are no issues with Twilio retreiving the TwiML needed in order to forward the inbound call to this instance of Twilio Client and verify that Twilio is attempting to make the outbound call to the correct Client instance.

Remember that in order to direct an inbound call to your Android application running Twilio Client you'll need to use the `<Dial>` verb and the `<Client>` noun:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Client>[your_client_instance_name]</Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Expanded my answer.  Let me know if that helps, otherwise I'll probably need more information on what you are seeing.

Comment: @Devin...hey I tried using Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken,this);
but that is not working.Stuck with the same problem

Comment: @Devin...I have one doubt,I am dialing to a number which is a twilio number. So the the twiml that I have generated is 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Dial callerId="//Twilio verified no"><Number>//a twilio number</Number></Dial></Response>

Comment: If you are dialing a Twilio phone number (PSTN) and want to bridge that incoming call with an instance of Twilio Client (VoIP), then you need to use the <Client> noun, not the number now.  If you want to go the other direction and make an inbound VoIP call from Client to Twilio and then bridge that to a phone number (PSTN) you'd use the <Number> noun.

Comment: @Devin....I changed my twiml to:
<Response><Dial><Client>//Client name</Client></Dial></Response>
 I can see the call in the Twilio log portal,the call is ringing and getting routed through my server,but nothing happens on my android device.
What can be the possible problem?

Comment: Even I am facing the same problem @akshay

Answer (score 0):

Implement these classes **Twilio.InitListener, DeviceListener, ConnectionListener**

and then initialize the device class

device = Twilio.createDevice(token, Your_Class.this);

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourClass.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            device.setIncomingIntent(pendingIntent);
```

This works for me well .. Hope works for you too!